# Java compilation/runtime classpath problems

Tags: java, classpath

I am trying to build a Java SNMP client. I have a folder on my Ubuntu desktop called snmpclient. Inside that folder I have the main class Client.java and the snmp.jar library, which is used by the main class.

I managed to compile it sucessfully using the following command on the terminal:

```
~/Desktop$ javac snmpclient/Client.java -classpath ./snmpclient/snmp.jar
```

Then I tried to run it with this command:

```
~/Desktop$ java snmpclient.Client -classpath ./snmpclient/snmp.jar
```

But I am getting a "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException" error, saying it can't find the classes of the snmp library. I unzipped the jar file to make sure the classes I am using are all there, and they are.

Any idea on how I can solve this?

Comment: Does your Client.java have `package snmpclient;` instruction in the top? Give us the error text also, it helps a lot.

Comment: Yep I do have the package outlined on the Client.java class. I'll paste the errors right now.

Comment: @BrianAgnew below got it right. Check out his answer.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking along the same lines just now: where your classes get compiled to, you need to tell Java about this location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rearrange your args thus:

```
~/Desktop$ java -classpath ./snmpclient/snmp.jar snmpclient.Client
```

such that your classpath preceeds the class to run. Note that your classpath defaults to the current directory if you don't specify `-classpath`, so your full invocation should be:

```
~/Desktop$ java -classpath ./snmpclient/snmp.jar:. snmpclient.Client
```

to specify the root directory where your classes reside (that's the dot), *plus* the SNMP jar file.

The `-classpath` arg consists of jar files and paths to directories separated by colons. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/index.html#classpath) for more info on setting the classpath.

Comment: That second line worked like a charm. I didn't understand yet what the ":." do after the classpath though. Could you explain? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I've amended the answer appropriately. Let me know if no good

Comment: Let me see if I got this: Without the colon the command won't work cause it will interpret everything as the classpath. With the colon it manages to separate what's the classpath and what's the class you want to invoke. Is that it? Anyway thanks, it helped a lot.

Comment: You need to specify the path to your classes (that's the dot) *and* the jar file that contains the 3rd party classes (that's the jar file). You can specify multiple entries in the classpath (e.g. many .jar files plus a couple of directories etc.)